# Order by score through other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm having a users model that has a method score, which actually gets a sum of the score of solved challenges :

```
  def score
    self.challenge_level_solutions.inject(0) do |sum, x|
        sum + x.challenge_level.points
    end
  end
```

Now, i have a Kaminari related controller action like :

```
  def index
    @users = User.page(params[:page])
  end
```

My problem is how i would go about displaying the user score in DESC order, that is show the users with a better score about others with a lower score. My view is :

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
    <%= user.username %> - <%= user.score %>
    <br>
<% end %>
```

and shows :

```
1. user1 - 0 
2. user2 - 0 
3. user3 - 2
```

Any ideas so that it shows properly, with user3 on the first place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def index
  @users = User.all.sort_by(&:score).reverse
  @users = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(2)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The ruby way to do this is use collection.sort_by

Example:

```
collection.sort_by{|o|o.score}
```

Chain .reverse/.reverse! if needed.

Comment: note there's also an ActiveRecord way, but it doesn't look like you're storing the value you want to sort by in the database, so that won't work for your case

Comment: yeap, i don't store this at all, i could probably do it with a counter_cache if i did, i think. Maybe it's better, performancewise, to do something like that.